# How do I update documents with MotorEngine

Tags: python, mongodb, tornado-motor, motorengine

I'm trying to update the `Projects` document name after filtering by id :

```
def update(project_id,project_name):      
     temp = Projects.objects.filter(id=ObjectId(project_id)).find_all()
     temp.name = project_name
     return temp.save(temp)
```

This throws up an error :

> return temp.save(temp) AttributeError: 'Future' object has no
>   attribute 'save'

So, I tried using the callbacks also (although the rest of the wiring does not make using the callback feasible here, so I'm looking for a solution without the callback) :

```
def update(project_id,project_name):
  Projects.objects.filter(id=ObjectId(project_id)).find_all(callback=update_handler())

def update_handler(temp):
  proj = Projects(temp)
  return proj.save()
```

Error :

> Projects.objects.filter(id=ObjectId(project_id)).find_all(callback=update_handler())
>       TypeError: update_handler() missing 1 required positional argument: 'temp'

Suggestions please!

Comment: Tagging users who have not already commented on your question does not send an alert to them, only users who have comments here get messages. But my point, the `objects.filter` syntax here looks more like django to me. Raw motor syntax is a bit different.

Comment: This is motorengine syntax : https://motorengine.readthedocs.org Built on top of motor I suppose.

Comment: No experience with Motorengine at all (and no setup to test), but looking at the documentation and github tests the callback should probably be `(callback=update_handler)` without the `()`. Also not sure `.find_all()` is the right thing to do here. See [github sample](https://github.com/heynemann/motorengine/blob/master/tests/test_document.py#L823)